# Port error when setting up Dev mode of Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, dev-mode

I'm setting up the development environment following the instructions on Hyperledger fabric's official website:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peer-chaincode-devmode.html
I have started the orderer successfully using:

```
ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISPROFILE=SampleDevModeSolo orderer
```

This command didn't work at first but it worked after I `cd fabric/sampleconfig`

```
2020-12-21 11:23:15.084 CST [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 009 Starting orderer:  Version: 2.3.0  Commit SHA: dc2e59b3c  Go version: go1.15.6  OS/Arch: darwin/amd64 
2020-12-21 11:23:15.084 CST [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 00a Beginning to serve requests
```

but when I start the peer using:

```
export PATH=$(pwd)/build/bin:$PATH 
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$(pwd)/sampleconfig
export FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=chaincode=debug
export CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
```

An error is spotted:

```
FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=chaincode=debug 
CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true

2020-12-21 11:25:13.047 CST [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:  Version: 2.3.0 Commit SHA: dc2e59b3c Go version: go1.15.6 OS/Arch: darwin/amd64 Chaincode: Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric   Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2020-12-21 11:25:13.048 CST [peer] getLocalAddress -> INFO 002 Auto-detected peer address: 10.200.83.208:7051 
2020-12-21 11:25:13.048 CST [peer] getLocalAddress -> INFO 003 Host is 0.0.0.0 , falling back to auto-detected address: 10.200.83.208:7051  Error: failed to initialize operations subsystem: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9443: bind: address already in use
```

this is the error:

```
Error: failed to initialize operations subsystem: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9443: bind: address already in use
```

I checked this issue and it seems this happens because the peer node is using the same port 9443 as the orderer node for the same service. How can I get the two nodes running separately? It seems the docker is running as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see your error, you can easily follow
`Error: failed to initialize operations subsystem: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9443: bind: address already in use`
It is said that the 9443 port is already in use.

---

It seems that you are not running the orderer and peer as separate containers on the docker-based virtual network, but running on the host pc.
This eventually seems to conflict with two servers requesting one port 9443 on your pc.\

---

Referring to the configuration below of `fabric-2.3/sampleconfig`, you can see that each port 9443 is assigned to the server. Assigning one of them to the other port solves this.

[fabric-2.3/sampleconfig/orderer.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v2.3.0/sampleconfig/orderer.yaml)

> configuration of orderer

```yaml
# orderer.yaml
...
Admin:
    # host and port for the admin server
    ListenAddress: 127.0.0.1:9443
...
```

[fabric-2.3/sampleconfig/core.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v2.3.0/sampleconfig/core.yaml)

> configuration of peer

```yaml
# core.yaml
...
operations:
    # host and port for the operations server
    # listenAddress: 127.0.0.1:9443
    listenAddress: 127.0.0.1:10443
...
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. But other ports get conflict too. Do you know how to run the orderer and peer processes in two docker containers? Thanks for your help.

Comment: When dealing with multiple containers, it is recommended to build a network through docker-compose. The same can be applied to the fabric, and if it is built through a container, only the port conflict on the host PC and the different network topology need to be considered. See the fabric's official sample here. [fabric-samples/docker-compose-test-net.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml)

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the port mapping / collision issue, but we've had great success using the new [Kubernetes Test Network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network-k8s) as a development platform running on a local system with a virtual Kubernetes cluster running in KIND (Kubernetes in Docker).

In this mode, applications can be developed using the Gateway client (exposed via a port forward or ingress), and smart contracts running As a Service can be launched either in the cluster OR run on the local host OS in a container, binary, or launched in a debugger.

The documentation for the [development setup](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network-k8s/docs/CHAINCODE.md#debugging-chaincode) is still sparse, but we'd love to hear feedback on the overall approach, as it offers an exponentially better experience for working with a test network in a development context.  In general the process of "port juggling" with Compose is no longer relevant when working on a local Kubernetes cluster.  In this mode, you can run services on the host network, instructing peers/orderers/etc. to connect to the remote process running on the host OS.